Building an application for phones on flutter flow that can connect to a desktop Program in java
I'm trying to build a mobile application for my School's Dentist. I can build it on flutter flow, and I can build the program in java for GUI thanks to YouTube. I still don't know how can I connect both to work harmoniously so that user logs in from their phone, database gets sent for booking the appointment on the java GUI at the dentist's office... this creates a full system for both the customer and the receptionist.
I'm not the best at back-end, but I'm trying to learn.
Is there such a way you can make the platform for both phones and computers so that we have no confusion in the future?
or should I proceed with making the app separately in flutter flow and find a way to connect it to the program using mySQL? if so? how does this happen and where do I start?
I now have a GUI on pc for the clinic in java AND i have the app on flutter flow, they are separated, how do I connect them?

Much too broad a topic for Stack Overflow. By the way, I would have used Vaadin Flow to build a web app in pure Java that runs on both the desktop computer and the mobile device. But there are many ways to eat a kiwi fruit. You will need to do much research to identify the various approaches, and then decide what works for you and your client. Get busy with your search engine. Once you learn about some alternatives, try opening a discussion on a forums site such as JavaRanch.com.
